# Is there a RRDTool .net equivalent

Tags: .net, monitoring, rrdtool

I need to monitor a lot of data, and i know that RRDTool is a good option, but entire app is c# so ill prefer some Microsoft way or .net port.

Is there a .net way of doing the same as RRDTool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [**NHawk**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk.aspx) can help?
"NHawk is an initiative to provide a thin, complete RRDtool provider for the .Net and Mono framework."

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately MHawk just launches RRDTool processes for each RRD command. SUggested MHawk connect to the librrd instead so that calls can be kept in process.

Comment: Did you mean NHawk or MHawk? A link to it would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a C# version there is one at google code. You can find the url and some background information in this [blog](http://blog.minidev.se/2010/02/10/Rrd4NetArePublic.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [RrdSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rrdsharp/) to do the same thing as RrdTool, completely in C#. I have no experience with [Rrd4Net](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4net/); it has 4+ months total development time compared to RrdSharp's 4+ years. (You do have to start somewhere!)

RrdSharp is a bit dusty (.NET v1.1; last update 2009-07-17), and the binary data file format is [not compatible with RrdTool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHawk.aspx?msg=3276387#xx3276387xx). However, the functionality you need is probably there.